# Openshift 3.11 logging to external ElasticSearch instance

Tags: ansible, openshift, redhat, ansible-inventory, openshift-enterprise

I have an external ElasticSearch instance that I'd like Fluentd and Kibana to leverage accordingly in OSE 3.11.  The ES instance is insecure at the moment, as this is simply a internal pilot.  Based on the OSE docs here (https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/aggregate_logging.html#sending-logs-to-an-external-elasticsearch-instance), I should be able to *update* a number of ES_* variables accordingly in the ElasticSearch deployment config.  The first issue is, the variables referenced in the docs don't exist in the ElasticSearch deployment config.

Secondly, I tried updating these values via the inventory file.  For example, for the property **openshift_logging_es_host**, the description claims: *The name of the Elasticsearch service where Fluentd should send logs.*

These were the values in my inventory file:

```
openshift_logging_install_logging=true
openshift_logging_es_ops_nodeselector={'node-role.kubernetes.io/infra':'true'}
openshift_logging_es_nodeselector={'node-role.kubernetes.io/infra':'true'}
openshift_logging_es_host='169.xx.xxx.xx'
openshift_logging_es_port='9200'
openshift_logging_es_ops_host='169.xx.xxx.xx'
openshift_logging_es_ops_port='9200'
openshift_logging_kibana_env_vars={'ELASTICSEARCH_URL':'http://169.xx.xxx.xx:9200'}
openshift_logging_es_ca=none
openshift_logging_es_client_cert=none
openshift_logging_es_client_key=none
openshift_logging_es_ops_ca=none
openshift_logging_es_ops_client_cert=none
openshift_logging_es_ops_client_key=none
```

The only variable above that seems to stick after uninstall/install of logging is openshift_logging_kibana_env_vars. I'm not sure why the others weren't respected - perhaps I'm missing one that triggers use of these vars.

In any case, after those attempts failed, I eventually found the values set on the logging-fluentd Daemon Set.  I can edit via CLI or the console to set the es host, port, client keys, certs, etc.  I also set the ops equivalents.  The fluentd logs confirms these values are set, however, it's attempting to use https in conjunction with the default fluentd/changeme id/pwd combo.

```
2019-03-08 11:49:00 -0600 [warn]: temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2019-03-08 11:54:00 -0600 error_class="Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure" error="Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"169.xx.xxx.xx\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\"https\", :user=>\"fluentd\", :password=>\"obfuscated\"})!" plugin_id="elasticsearch-apps"
```

So, ideally, I'd like to set these as inventory variables, and everything just works.  If anybody has a suggestion to fix that issue, please let me know.

Less than ideal, I can modify the ES deployment config or the Fluentd Dameon Set post-install and set the values required, assuming someone knows how to avoid https?

Thanks for any input you might have.

**Update:**

I managed to get this working, but not via the properties documented or the provided suggestion.  I ended up going through the various playbooks to identify the vars being used.  I also had to setup mutual TLS, as when I specified the cert files locations to be none/undefined, the logs indicated a 'File not found'.  Essentially, none or undefined gets translated to "", which it tries to open as a file.  So, this was the magic combination of properties that will get you 99.9% of the way.

```
openshift_logging_es_host=169.xx.xxx.xxx
openshift_logging_fluentd_app_host=169.xx.xxx.xxx
openshift_logging_fluentd_ops_host=169.xx.xxx.xxx
openshift_logging_fluentd_ca_path='/tmp/keys/client-ca.cer'
openshift_logging_fluentd_key_path='/tmp/keys/client.key'
openshift_logging_fluentd_cert_path='/tmp/keys/client.cer'
openshift_logging_fluentd_ops_ca_path='/tmp/keys/client-ca.cer'
openshift_logging_fluentd_ops_key_path='/tmp/keys/client.key'
openshift_logging_fluentd_ops_cert_path='/tmp/keys/client.cer'
```

**Notes:**

- You need to copy the keys to `/tmp/keys` prior.
- Upon completion, you will notice that OPS_HOST will not be set on the Daemon Set. I left it in the properties above as I think it's just a bug, and perhaps will be fixed beyond 3.11 which is what I'm using.  To adjust this simply `oc edit ds/logging-fluentd` and modify accordingly.

With these changes, the log data gets sent to my external ES instance.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is a less ideal solution which is sending logs to external log aggregator using `secure-forward.conf`, refer around [Configuring Fluentd to Send Logs to an External Log Aggregator](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/aggregate_logging.html#aggregated-fluentd) section for more defails.

You can configure [elasticsearch output plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/out_elasticsearch) as well as `secure_forward` plugin without `https`.

For instnace,

```
# oc edit cm logging-fluentd -n openshift-logging
...
  secure-forward.conf: |
    <store>
      @type elasticsearch
      host external.es.example.com
      port 9200
    </store>
...
```

**UPDATE**: I've tested against a external `fluentd` instead of `ES`, because I have not a external `ES` instance in my hand. For checking log activation, I also printed out logs as file during test.

```
  secure-forward.conf: |
    <store>
    @type forward
     <server>
       host external.fluented.example.com
       port 24224
     </server>
    </store>
    <store>
    @type file
    path /var/log/secure-forward-test.log
    </store>
```

I've verified above configuration can transfer the logs to external `fluentd` and local log files.

Comment: I don't have an external log aggregator at the moment, so, I limited my config map edits to the elasticsearch output plugin.  I can see a /user/output-es-config.conf on the pod, but those changes are not taking effect.  Do I need to include it somehow?

I still plan to pursue the inventory/playbook route even if this addresses the issue temporarily.

Comment: AFAIK you can not change directly `/user/output-es-config.conf` unless rebuilding `logging-fluentd image` with new one you changed. the customizable config file is limited such as `secure-forward.conf`. So you should try to `configure secure-forward.conf` in `logging-fluentd` `ConfigMap` for your needs.

Comment: I attempted your suggestion, however, I'm seeing this in the fluent pod log:

`[warn]: no patterns matched tag="output_tag"`

Comment: @MB I've updated my answer to add my test configuration. Check it whether or not work for you.